# Generate array of elements within a div using JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, bootstrap-4

Im working on a travel website where the users have an option to plan their own trip. They will be preseted with an input box where they can choose how many days their trip is going to last. However im struggeling to find out how to create an array of elements corresponding to the amount of days they select. For example if they select "4" days then 4 boxes with uniqe titles and buttons will appear. Im open to work in php or javascript, thank you for the help!

Example of what the code should produce.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgwxyoj9/1/)

```
<input type="number"> <!-- input days -->

    <div class="container"> <!-- Bootstrap Container -->
<div class="row"> <!-- Bootstrap Row -->
   <div class="col" style="background-color: red; height: 6em;"> <!-- Day container -->
      <h1 class="title">Day 1</h1> <!-- Title with UNIQE name -->
      <button>Select trip</button> <!-- Button -->
   </div> <!-- End of day container -->
   <div class="w-100" style="height: 2em;"></div> <!-- Spacing -->


   <div class="col" style="background-color: red; height: 6em;">
      <h1 class="title">Day 2</h1>
      <button>Select trip</button>
   </div>
   <div class="w-100" style="height: 2em;"></div>

   <div class="col" style="background-color: red; height: 6em;">
      <h1 class="title">Day 3</h1>
      <button>Select trip</button>
   </div>
   <div class="w-100" style="height: 2em;"></div>
   
   <div class="col" style="background-color: red; height: 6em;">
      <h1 class="title">Day 4</h1>
      <button>Select trip</button>
   </div>

</div> <!-- End of row -->
</div> <!-- End of container -->
```

Comment: You show example code in the link, so what is the problem you have in implementing that in your code?

Comment: You could use a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) which you clone X number of times and modify accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `insertAdjacentHTML` to generate your form, kindly take a look the below example:

```js
document.getElementById('gen').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var days = document.getElementById('days').value;
  var trips = document.getElementById('trips');
  trips.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i=0; i<days; i++) {
    trips.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="day'+(i+1)+'"><h1 class="title">Day '+(i+1)+'</h1><button>Select Trip</button></div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="days" style="width:20px;" value="1"><button id="gen">Enter</button>
<div id="trips"></div>
```